# Loop and Accumulate Sum from Pandas Column Made of Lists

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, my Pandas data frame looks like the following

| Row_X |
| --- |
| ["Medium, "High", "Low"] |
| ["Medium"] |

My intention is to iterate through the list in each row such that:

```
summation = 0

for value in df["Row_X"]:
     if "High" in value:
          summation = summation + 10
     elif "Medium" in value:
          summation = summation + 5
     else:
          summation= summation + 0
```

Finally, I wish to apply this to each and create a new column that looks like the following:

| Row_Y |
| --- |
| 15 |
| 10 |

My assumption is that either np.select() or apply() can play into this but thus far have encountered errors with implementing either.

Comment: Careful, `sum` is a bult-in function

Comment: Good call, changed the example.

Comment: When dealing with pandas, always try to avoid iterating through the dataframe. Use apply instead

Answer (score 4):

We can do:

```
mapper = {'Medium' : 5, 'High' : 10}
```

---

```
df['Row_Y'] = [sum([mapper[word] for word in l 
                    if word in mapper]) 
               for l in df['Row_X']]
```

If **pandas version > 0.25.0** We can use

```
df['Row_Y'] = df['Row_X'].explode().map(mapper).sum(level=0)
```

---

```
print(df)

                 Row_X  Row_Y
0  [Medium, High, Low]     15
1             [Medium]      5
```

Comment: i like the use of explode/groupby

Comment: Now better with `sum(level=0)` I forgot it @Kenan

Answer (score 1):

Map your function to the series

```
import pandas as pd

def function(x):
    summation = 0
    for i in x:
        if "High" in i:
            summation += 10
        elif "Medium" in i:
            summation += 5
        else:
            summation += 0
    return summation


df = pd.DataFrame({'raw_x': [['Medium', 'High', 'Low'], ['Medium']]})
df['row_y'] = df['raw_x'].map(function)
```

You can do it in a shorter format with

```
mapping = {'High': 10, 'Medium': 5, 'Low': 0}
df['raw_y'] = df['raw_x'].map(lambda x: sum([mapping[i] if i in mapping else 0 for i in x]))
```

```
print(df)

                 raw_x  row_y
0  [Medium, High, Low]     15
1             [Medium]      5
```

Comment: Apologies, added for loop to reflect cumulative summation that I wish to accomplish.  Would this change the mapping drastically?

Comment: I would add `if i in mapping` to avoid `KeyError`

Comment: Getting all 0 in the response for each output.  Wondering if the datatype in the column is read as a list.

Comment: for the short approach make sure your mapping dict has all column values

Comment: @ask39 check `df['ask'].apply(type).eq(list)` let us Know if you get a False

Comment: Interesting, all true and yet still returning all zeros in the output column.

Comment: Never mind, spelling error induced from the dictionary. All good now, thank you kindly!

Comment: you can use: `mapping[i.lower()] if i in mapping else 0 for i in x` and write all mapper's keys in lowercase to avoid problems @ask39

Answer (score 1):

Maybe on a cleaner side, convert to a `Series` and directly use `map`

```
mapp = {'Medium' : 5, 'High' : 10}
df['Row_Y'] = df['Row_X'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).map(mapp).sum())
df

            Row_X         Row_Y
0   [Medium, High, Low]   15.0
1   [Medium]              5.0
```

Comment: Yes, thats the way to do it. Using map to iterate and sum is the best approach

Comment: @JoeFerndz 
apply is a loop and create a pd.Series in each row is ineffcient, 
in my opinion the other solutions with map and apply are more efficient

Comment: Agree. I see @ansev response. Thats a good one. Good learning

Comment: Yes https://stackoverflow.com/a/65961876/2455169 is the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work -

```py
vals = {"High":10, "Medium":5, "Low":0}
df['Row_Y'] = df.apply(lambda row : sum(vals[i] for i in row['Row_X']) ,axis=1)
```